# VSTest task in Azure devops timing out after 60 minutes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I implemented a test method using MSTest2, the execution of the test code takes about a minute. This test uses DataTestMethod with DynamicData source. The result of expansion of the dynamic data results in more than a 100 tests. When I run the test in Azure Pipeline, the test times out exactly at 60 minutes. I've tried several options

- Timeout on job
- customRunTimePerBatchValue on the test input.

Neither works! It makes using DataTestMethod useless. Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Regards.

Previously I had mentioned job above when I actually meant Task as that's what I had tried. Putting the timeout on the job seems to fix it.

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts

Comment: @DanielMann, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Daniel,

If your project is private and you are using hosted agent, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations): One free parallel job that can run for up to **60 minutes each time**, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month. You can **pay for additional capacity** per parallel job. Paid parallel jobs remove the monthly time limit and allow you to run each job for up to **360** minutes (6 hours). [Buy Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#microsoft-hosted-cicd).

Another way is [configure self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and open build definition->click option tab and change the value of field Build job timeout in minutes to 0, then it should be work. We could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#timeouts) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Liu - PM'd you offline.

Comment: Hi @loganwol, I am online now. It seems that you have solved the problem and thanks for the sharing

Comment: Thanks for clue, @Vito.

Answer (score 2):

Setting timeoutInMinutes: 0 on the job (not on the VSTest task) seems to remove the 60 minute restriction.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

For self-hosted agents, in case your pipeline is built using 'yaml' file (a CI pipeline), then you may want to set the VSTest@2 as a task under 'jobs' as shown below:

```
jobs:
- job: myJob
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  pool:
    name: myTestAgentPool
  steps:
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Test run for Test plans'
    inputs:
      testSelector: testPlan
      testPlan: xxxxx
      testSuite: xxxxx
```

Setting 'timeoutInMinutes' to 0 will remove any timeout limitation for all steps under 'myJob'. You can setup different jobs likewise.